# Why 1 norm of reconstruction error is not used/minimized for low rank approximation using PCA?

Tags: pca, error, dimensionality-reduction, svd

In pca, I see reconstruction error is calculated in terms of either frobenius norm or spectral norm. And I also saw they have a closed bound in terms of singular values.
My question is why 1 norm of reconstruction error is not used as a performance metrics or why 1 norm of reconstruction error is not minimized?

Comment: Seems relevant: http://ajou.ac.kr/~nojunk/papers/L1PCA_TPAMI.pdf

Comment: PCA minimizes L2 norm. Are you asking why it does not *also* minimize the L1 norm (meaning that you think that it's equivalent), or are you asking why PCA was developed with L2 and not L1 minimization?

Comment: Is it possible to answer both? @amoeba